# Are changes made to .git/hooks/pre-commit part of the repo after push ? Or are they just present in my local?

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I want to run my tests before every commit.
So under .git/hooks/pre-commit file, I write the code to run my tests.
This works fine in my local. However, I don't find the changes I made to the pre-commit file present in the git stage. Nor is it part of the PR.
Will this be available to anyone who clones or pulls the branch?
If now how can I make this global to the project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+push

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusehookstopreventusersfrommakingcertainchanges